# CSS3 inverted/reverse rounded corner for a tooltip

Tags: css, retina-display, masking, css-mask

I'm trying to create a tooltip that looks like this using CSS:

[image: reversed rounded corners]

This is how i'm trying to solve it: http://jsfiddle.net/NXLuZ/

So, basically i'm using css3 masking:

```
div:after {
    width: 61px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle 10px at 0px 0, transparent 0, transparent 10px, black 11px);
    top: -10px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```

Looks good on regular displays, but you can see the problem when you're viewing it on a retina display or when you're trying to zoom in:

[image: The issue]

Because i'm using a gradient as a mask, it looks a bit blurry when the color changes in the gradient. Its important to mention, that the rounded corner needs to be transparent, because the background is not fixed behind it.

Any idea how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Sometimes an image is just the best option like an `SVG` (scalable vector graphic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a box shadow:

```
.demo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 106px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 0 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius:10px 0 10px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);    
    line-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#dbdbdb;
}

.demo:before {
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -26px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    display: block;
}

.demo:after {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    top: -10px;
    right: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 50px 0px 0px 50px white;
    clip: rect(0px, 60px, 50px, 0px);
    display: block;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xN83/)

Comment: Great, this looks a lot sharper!